# Promise all issue ( I get empty response )

Tags: promise

How can I solve it? When I try to get a result from promise all, I get an empty array.

```
async function getMessage(arr) {
        let response = [];
        for (let count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
            let protocol = await arr[count].link.split(':')[0];
            if (protocol === 'http') {
                await http.get(arr[count].link, async (res) => {
                    response.push(`${arr[count].link} - ${res.statusCode}\n`);
                });
            } else {
                await https.get(arr[count].link, async (res) => {
                    response.push(`${arr[count].link} - ${res.statusCode}\n`);
                });
            }
        }
        return Promise.all(response)
            .then((data) => {
                  //data === []
                return data;
            });
    }
```

Comment: Which http library are you using?

Answer (score 1):

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

I assume you're using node's native `http` and `https` module. It's true they're async functions, but they cannot be used with **await** straight, since they're using **callback** not **Promise**.

Afaik, you can either manually "promisify" it with [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original), or use some 3rd party like [isomorphic-fetch](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) which already promisified it for you.

Example:

```js
const sayHelloWithoutPromise = () => {
  setTimeout(() => console.log('hello'), 0)
}

(async function() {
  await sayHelloWithoutPromise()
  console.log('world!')
})()
```

```js
const sayHelloWithPromise = () => {
  return new Promise(r => 
    setTimeout(() => r(console.log('hello')), 0)
  )
}

(async function() {
  await sayHelloWithPromise()
  console.log('world!')
})()
```